# How to get songs from album in android?

Tags: android

I am getting all album details. Now I want to get all songs from any album. How to query for songs in a specific album?

I've used this code to get album details:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.getContentUri("external"),
                new String[] { 
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST, 
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS, 
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM}, null, null,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM + " ASC");
```

Please anybody help me.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've got!

Comment: Hi, check the question now. I've given the code

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing? Which columns are you retrieving? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Kumar, I want to displays songs albumwise. I listed all albums. Now when I click on any album, it should retrieve all songs from that album.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query songs of an album with CursorLoader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065377/query-songs-of-an-album-with-cursorloader)

Answer (score -1):

You can write simple sqlite query for 'selection' string on contentResolver.query by fields on MediaStore.Audio.Media properties.  Please check my answer on [How to get songs and other media from an Album ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337949/how-to-get-songs-and-other-media-from-an-album-id/35746126#35746126)