# Query songs of an album with CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I'd like to get the list of songs of an album by querying the `MediaStore` with `CursorLoader`

How can i do this ? I can get all the songs of the device with this code :

```
static final String[] TRACK_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE}; 

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {  
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    String select = null;  
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,  
                    TRACK_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,  
                    sortOrder);  
}
```

What should I add to the code or modification to filter songs of a particular Album ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go step by step

**Step 1 Look the names of albums loaded on you phone**

To request cursor for Album information

```
String[] columns = { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM };

cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        columns, null, null, null);
```

**Step 2 Once you find all album names.You can write down the desired album name and query songs from it**

To request cursor containing song information for particular album

```
String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
          MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
          MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
          MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
          MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, };

      String where = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM
          + "=?";

      String whereVal[] = { Album name from which you want songs };

      String orderBy = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;

      cursor = managedQuery(
          MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
          where, whereVal, orderBy);
```

Now return this cursor.

For your reference below is Source code to retrieve Album name and all songs in it.

```
package org.vipul;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] columns = { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM };

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.v("Vipul",
                        cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // I want to list down song in album Rolling Papers (Deluxe Version)

        String[] column = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, };

        String where = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + "=?";

        String whereVal[] = { "Rolling Papers (Deluxe Version)" };

        String orderBy = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;

        cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                column, where, whereVal, orderBy);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.v("Vipul",
                        cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: hello vipul, this was something i have been looking for and could not find anywhere, after a lot of search finally a neat and easy to understand code, i am currently learning android and would like to know can we extract the album info like album image and show the same using a listview.the way it is in all media players, thanks for such an excellent code

Comment: This is the most complete answer for querying albums and its contents. And there is no obvious way from looking at code in MediaStore.java. The solution is not trivial.

Comment: Instead of matching the album name, I matched the ID, as in String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID + "=?";