# How to filter songs in listView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, filter, audio-player, android-music-player

I have a listView filled up with all songs on sdcard, can i filter them by name using an ediText or something else (like a SearchBar) and update the listview?Thanks, this is how I fill up the listview:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void init_phone_music_grid() {
            System.gc();
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
            musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    proj, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 120000", null, null);
            count = musiccursor.getCount();
            musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

            musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);

            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


      }

  private OnItemClickListener musicgridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
    long id) {

                System.gc();
                  music_column_index = musiccursor
    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                  musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);

                  String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                  String canzone=filename.replace("/storage/sdcard0/", "");
                  canzone=canzone.replace("Music/", "");
                  canzone=canzone.replace("media/", "");
                  canzone=canzone.replace("Ringtones/", "");
                  t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                  t.setWidth(130);
                  t.setSingleLine(true);
                  t.setText(canzone);

                  try {
                        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                              mMediaPlayer.reset();
                        }
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
                        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                  } catch (Exception e) {

                  }
            }
      };         
      public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context mContext;

            public MusicAdapter(Context c) {
                  mContext = c;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                  return count;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                  return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                  return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                System.gc();
                String id = null;
                TextView tv;
                if (convertView == null) {
                tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
                } else{
                tv = (TextView) convertView;
                }
                musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                tv.setText(id);
                return tv;
                }
      }
```

This is the updated code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    init_phone_music_grid(null);
    //Controllo();
    edittext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {


            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                init_phone_music_grid(edittext.getText().toString());

            }
        });
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void init_phone_music_grid(String a) {
            System.gc();
            String sortOrder=null;
            if(a!=null){
                sortOrder=MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE +a;
            }

            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
    musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    proj, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 120000", null, sortOrder);
            count = musiccursor.getCount();
            musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

            musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);

            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


      }

      private OnItemClickListener musicgridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
    long id) {

                System.gc();
                  music_column_index = musiccursor
    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                  musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);

                  String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                  String canzone=filename.replace("/storage/sdcard0/", "");
                  canzone=canzone.replace("Music/", "");
                  canzone=canzone.replace("media/", "");
                  canzone=canzone.replace("Ringtones/", "");
                  t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                  t.setWidth(130);
                  t.setSingleLine(true);
                  t.setText(canzone);

                  try {
                        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                              mMediaPlayer.reset();
                        }
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
                        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                  } catch (Exception e) {

                  }


            }

      };
```

Comment: have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android/14663821#14663821 This might help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you sort stuffs from mediastore

```
String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
```

if you want to sort it by artists or something else..just replace the "TITLE"part with whatever you dersire..

If you find my answer useful,accept it

Edit:Sorry i forgot where you will put this sort order thing

```
musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    proj, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 120000", null, null);
```

in this line of node..replace the last "null" with sortorder,and you will get sorted list...

Comment: When I try to sort my list the app crash and I have this error:

AndroidRuntime   android.database.squlite.SQLiteException: no such column: titleT(code 1):,while compiling SELECT_id, _data, _display_name, _size FROM audio WHERE (duraion>=120000) ORDER BY titleT

Comment: use this code....
String sortOrder=MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME+"ASC";
musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    proj, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 120000", null, sortOrder);

Comment: Show the code again which you are using.......and the logcat please,i would suggest creating a new question

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried this in onCreate:

init_phone_music_grid(null);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      
       
    
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
     init_phone_music_grid(e.getText().toString());
     
    }
   });

Comment: and i modified init_phone_music_grid():

private void init_phone_music_grid(String a) {
          System.gc();
          String sortOrder=null;
          if(a!=null){
           sortOrder=MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + "ASC";
          }
          
          String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
  MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
  musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
  proj, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 120000", null, sortOrder);

Comment: instead of line String sorOrder=null,try this
String sortOrder=new String();

Comment: String a is the text written in edittext, if it's null the list keep the same.. when I write in the edittext it sort the list by that text.
It will be not null at afterTextChanged metod

Comment: yeah i understood,did you try what i posted??**instead of line String sorOrder=null,try this String sortOrder=new String(); **

Comment: Yes but I have always the same error.. when I start writing the name of the song it crash.. this is the error:

11-17 14:48:50.128: E/AndroidRuntime(21458): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "T": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, _data, _display_name, _size FROM audio WHERE (duration>= 120000) ORDER BY title T

Comment: and did you try display name instead of title as i suggested earlier??
MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME??

Comment: Yeah, always that error with _display_name in place of title.. the last letter is the one I try to type

Comment: Yes, but sorting the list for letters the first would be the song I'm looking for

Comment: if you want tosearch for particular song..you can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065377/query-songs-of-an-album-with-cursorloader/11066095#11066095