# How to get songs and other media from an Album ID?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to get songs and other MEDIA details from Album Id. All I have is Album Id and I tried many solutions but none of them succeed.

My code snippet:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri mediaUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, albumId);
        Log.wtf("SKJDBKJ", mediaUri.toString());
        Cursor mediaCursor = contentResolver.query(mediaUri, null, null, null, null);

        // if the cursor is null.
        if(mediaCursor != null && mediaCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            Log.wtf("DSJK", "entered cursor");
            //get Columns
            int titleColumn = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM);
            int idColumn = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

            // Store the title, id and artist name in Song Array list.
            do
            {
                long thisId = mediaCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = mediaCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = mediaCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                Log.wtf("Title", thisTitle);

                // Add the info to our array.
                songArrayList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
            }
            while (mediaCursor.moveToNext());

            // For best practices, close the cursor after use.
            mediaCursor.close();
        }
```

Log for `mediaUri` returns path to current album, e.g. : `content://media/external/audio/media/41`.
Someone tell me how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out myself after a LOT of trial and errors. I don't know if it's the best and safest way to do so, but as far as it's working I am happy.

I changed my code a bit and compared Album IDs. Here's the snippet:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Log.wtf("SKJDBKJ", mediaUri.toString());
        Cursor mediaCursor = contentResolver.query(mediaUri, null, null, null, null);

        // if the cursor is null.
        if(mediaCursor != null && mediaCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            Log.wtf("DSJK", "entered cursor");
            //get Columns
            int titleColumn = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int albumId = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);

            // Store the title, id and artist name in Song Array list.
            do
            {
                long thisId = mediaCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                long thisalbumId = mediaCursor.getLong(albumId);
                String thisTitle = mediaCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = mediaCursor.getString(artistColumn);

                // Add the info to our array.
                if(this.albumId == thisalbumId)
                {
                    Log.wtf("SAME2SAME", String.valueOf(thisalbumId));
                    Log.wtf("SAME2SAME", String.valueOf(this.albumId));
                    songArrayList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
                }
            }
            while (mediaCursor.moveToNext());

            // For best practices, close the cursor after use.
            mediaCursor.close();
        }
```

I changed:

1. `Albums` to `Media` in `MediaStore.Audio.Audio.xxx`.
2. Got the `album Id` of `Media`.
3. Compared that to `album Id` I receive from `bundle extras`.
4. Only add those songs in the `arrayList`.
   I guess this'll be the way for `Artists` too.

Comment: How to get Album Art from album ID

Answer (score 6):

I have done it by myself.You can write simple sqlite query for 'selection' string on contentResolver.query .This example can show you how to get songs by album Id. I think this is best way.

```
    ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
    String selection = "is_music != 0";

    if (albumId > 0) {
        selection = selection + " and album_id = " + albumId;
    }

    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
    };
    final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int position = 1;
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Song song = new Song();
                song.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
                song.setDuration(cursor.getLong(4));
                song.setArtist(cursor.getString(1));
                song.setPath(cursor.getString(2));
                song.setPosition(position);
                song.setAlbumId(cursor.getLong(6));

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Media", e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

when you put the cursor.movenext function in to the while loop, the first line of 
MediaStore database will be passed without saving the data because the function move the cursor and then check so its better to make a value instead of putting the movenext function into the while.

```
  try {
            Projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM
            , MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,                                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Projection, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                columns[i] = cursor.getColumnIndex(Projection[i]);
            }

            Music tempMusic = new Music();

            while (next) {
                tempMusic.setName(cursor.getString(columns[0]));
                tempMusic.setAlbum(cursor.getString(columns[1]));
                tempMusic.setArtist(cursor.getString(columns[2]));
                tempMusic.setUri(cursor.getString(columns[3]));
                tempMusic.setSize(cursor.getDouble(columns[4]));
                if(!cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    next=false;
                }
                musicss.add(tempMusic);

                tempMusic = new Music();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Bitmap getAlbumArt(Long albumId) {
        Bitmap albumArt = null;
        try {
            final Uri AlbumArtUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(AlbumArtUri, albumId);
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = GlobalSongList.getInstance().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

            if (pfd != null) {
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                albumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return albumArt;
    }
```

ALBUM_ID is a field in the MediaStore and you can query it in the same way you query for title,artist,etc.

```
    public Long getAlbumId(String id)
    {
        Cursor musicCursor;
        String[] mProjection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};
        String[] mArgs = {id};
        musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, mProjection, MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + " = ?", mArgs, null);
        musicCursor.moveToFirst();
        Long albumId=musicCursor.getLong(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
        return albumId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did.
Works perfect.

```
String selection= MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+"!=0";
    String[] projection={
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
    };

    Cursor cursor=getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,selection,null,"title asc");
    List<String> data=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> songs=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> artists=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> albums=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> album_id=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> durations=new ArrayList<>();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        if(cursor.getString(5).equals(mAlbumId)) {
            data.add(cursor.getString(1));
            songs.add(cursor.getString(2));
            artists.add(cursor.getString(3));
            albums.add(cursor.getString(4));
            album_id.add(mAlbumId);
            durations.add(cursor.getString(6));
        }
    }
```