# After clicking on song from the listview,new activity is opening but song is not playing

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a musicplayer app.for that iam getting list of song from device but when iam clicking on song new activity is opening but song is not playing its just opening the activity thats it

I check checked code many times but didnt find any solution
if i use different method for getting device songs then its working but that method not finding all songs but only few songs.

playlist activity

```
public class PlayListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ = 7;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 5;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_MEDIA = 99;
    public static ArrayList<TrackObjects> songsList;
    private ListView songView;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);
        songView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songlist);
        songsList = new ArrayList<TrackObjects>();

        songView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int
                    position, long l) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(PlayListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                i1.putExtra("pos", position);
                i1.putExtra("songs", songsList);
                startActivity(i1);

            }
        });

        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        Collections.sort(songsList, new Comparator<TrackObjects>() {
            public int compare(TrackObjects a, TrackObjects b) {
                return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
            }
        });
        TracksAdapter songAdt = new TracksAdapter(PlayListActivity.this, songsList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_MEDIA);
        } else {
            getSongList();
        }

    }

    public void getSongList() {


        //retrieve song info
        ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();

        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

        if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //add songs to list
            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                songsList.add(new TrackObjects(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_MEDIA:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    getSongList();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

MainActivity(Songs Playing activity) :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static MediaPlayer mp;
    int position;
    SeekBar sb;
    ArrayList mySongs;
    Thread updateSeekBar;
    ImageButton pause, forward, reverse, next, previous;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        forward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.forward);

        previous = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
        reverse = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reverse);
        sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        updateSeekBar = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                int currentPosition = 0;
                while (currentPosition < totalDuration) {
                    try {
                        sleep(500);
                        currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                        sb.setProgress(currentPosition);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle b = i.getExtras();
        assert b != null;
        mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
        position = b.getInt("pos",0);
            Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
        if (mp!=null) {

            mp= (MediaPlayer) MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, u);
                mp.start();

                sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                updateSeekBar.start();

                sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i,
                                                  boolean b) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                    }
                });
                pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                            pause.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.play_button);
                            mp.pause();

                        } else {
                            pause.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.pause);
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    }
                });
                forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                        mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition() + 5000);
                    }
                });
                reverse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                        mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition() - 5000);
                    }
                });
                next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                        position = ((position + 1) % mySongs.size());
                        Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
                previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                        position = ((position - 1) < 0) ? (mySongs.size() - 1) : (position - 1);
                        Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(
                                position).toString());//%mysongs so that it do not go to invalid position
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

TracksAdapter(Songslist adapter) :

```
public class TracksAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<TrackObjects> tracks;
    private LayoutInflater trackInf;

    public TracksAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<TrackObjects> theTracks) {
        tracks = theTracks;
        trackInf = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tracks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //map to song layout
        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") LinearLayout songLay = (LinearLayout) trackInf.inflate
                (R.layout.songtracks, parent, false);
        //get title and artist views
        TextView trackView = (TextView) songLay.findViewById(R.id.track_title);
        TextView artistView = (TextView) songLay.findViewById(R.id.track_artist);
        //get song using position
        TrackObjects currSong = tracks.get(position);
        //get title and artist strings
        trackView.setText(currSong.getTitle());

        artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());
        //set position as tag
        songLay.setTag(position);
        return songLay;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

TrackObjects(Objects class) :

```
public class TrackObjects implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String artist;

    public TrackObjects(long id, String title, String artist) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
    }
    protected TrackObjects(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readLong();
        title = in.readString();
        artist = in.readString();
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }
    {
    }}
```

Comment: Check whether you are getting your songs list on the playing activity . You have declared your trackObject as serializable but retrieving as parcelable. Also you are just passing you fetched trackobject to your media player. Instead you should pass your song url

Comment: Yes im getting songs list in playlist activity.if i dont declare trackobject as serializable then it showing errors and can you please tell me how to get selected song from list by passing song url..

Comment: Check the answer posted below.

Comment: Its not getting that SongUrl in main activity its showing cannot resolve getSongUrl and can you please tell what should we have to add in  " songsList.add(new TrackObjects(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));" in playlist activity

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not passing url to the media player in your MainActivity. Your code is something like:

```
mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
position = b.getInt("pos",0);
Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
```

Here,

```
mySongs.get(position).toString();
```

It will return `TrackObjects` from list and using `toString()` will return object reference data. So ultimately you are not passing any url to the media player.

Solution:
Add a new string variable in `TrackObjects` class such as `private String songUrl;` and to get this use following line instead of above line

```
Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).getSongUrl());
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Its not getting that SongUrl in main activity its showing cannot resolve getSongUrl and can you please tell what should we have to add in  " songsList.add(new TrackObjects(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));" in playlist activity

Comment: As I have mentioned, you have add URI in your Model class if fetching from local storage. Now to fetch the URI, you can get using simple Google. You can get basic idea and help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337949/how-to-get-songs-and-other-media-from-an-album-id/35746126 or https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.

Comment: i think i have done the pretty much  as same  as that stackoverflow answer mentioned by you  but in playlist activity if i use diffrent method(arraylist<File>....) for getting device songs then it working but not with this method and when i debug the mysongs list showing songs and also the position of song which i selected but its not playing  pls help..

Comment: If you are done like the stackoverflow link then please update your code becasue I cannot see `song.setPath(cursor.getString(2));` in your code as shown there with vote count 4. Further, it would be good if you show the log for the URI that you pass to mediaplayer in `mp.create(Context, Uri)` method.

Comment: i tried that  but  it's not helping. the problem im getting is somewhere  in mediaplayer i think

Comment: Please show me the url log that you are passing so that I will be sure and would like to check in the other section of your code.

Comment: If i use different method like environment.externalstorage... then its working but not with this method